# Design JFrame with mounting multiples JPanels?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm new java GUI developer and I have a question.

Is possible to create a Jframe with multiples Jpanels? My idea is create a class with the components added in the JPanel and from another class create the JFrame adding multiples objects of the JPanel Class.

At the moment I'm doing test:

```
public class Principal {

    private JFrame window;

    public Principal(){

        window = new JFrame("Principal");        
    }

    /**
     * @return the finestra
     */
    public JFrame getFinestra() {
        return window;
    }
}`
```

**Child Class**

```
public class Childs {

    private JPanel panel;
    private JLabel text1;

    public Childs(){
        panel = new JPanel();
        text1 = new JLabel();

        text1.setText("TEXT");
        panel.add(text1);
    }

    /**
     * @return the panel
     */
    public JPanel getPanel() {
        return panel;
    }
}
```

**TestFrame Class**

```
public class TestFrame {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Principal p = new Principal();
        Childs c = new Childs();
        Childs c2 = new Childs();

        p.getFinestra().add(c.getPanel());
        p.getFinestra().add(c2.getPanel());
        p.getFinestra().setVisible(true);
    }
}
`
```

Comment: *"Is possible to create a Jframe with multiples Jpanels?"*  Yes.  In fact, **most** real world GUIs have multiple panels.  I use them to allow setting different layouts in different parts of the GUI.  See [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) that combines layouts.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I going to read the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is certainly possible to have multiple JPanels in a JFrame. You can get the component `Container` from the JFrame with `getContentPane()`, which in your example would work as

```
p.getFinestra().getContentPane();
```

To understand how to place your `JPanel`s to the `JFrame`, you should study some `Layout`s. Here is a good resource and this site has many more: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html

For example to use a `FlowLayout` (the default one)

```
p.getFinestra().getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
p.getFinestra().getContentPane().add(c);
p.getFinestra().getContentPane().add(c2);

//It is also a good habit to call pack() before setting to visible
p.getFinestra().pack()
p.getFinestra().setVisible(true);
```

And as a short lesson in English, the plural of *child* is *children*.

Comment: I already understand it. I have create the frame and I put the content panel and I add the components. You're right, child -> children :( –